# Google Search Console not finding all Sitemaps within Sitemap Index. How to fix?

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap, xml

I created a [valid](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en) Sitemap Index (/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap_index.xml) for a site as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap1.txt</loc>
<lastmod>2019-12-10T18:24:17+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap2.txt</loc>
<lastmod>2019-12-10T18:24:17+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap3.txt</loc>
<lastmod>2019-12-10T18:24:17+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
.
.
.
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap536.txt</loc>
<lastmod>2019-12-10T18:24:17+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Each Sitemap Child is a simple list of 49,999 URLs and they are all under 10MB in size.

I uploaded the Sitemap Index and all of the Sitemap Children to the server.  I double-checked to make sure the Sitemap Index and all the Sitemap Children are all accessible on the server, and they are.

However, when I submit the Sitemap Index to Google via the Google Search Console, I get a success message saying "Sitemap index processed successfully", **no errors are reported anywhere**, and yet it only lists 9 of the 106 Sitemap Children (and they all happen to start with 'sitemap1'):

```
Sitemap                         Status  Discovered URLs
/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap1.txt   Success 49,999
/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap10.txt  Success 49,999
/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap100.txt Success 49,999
/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap101.txt Success 49,999
/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap102.txt Success 49,999
/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap103.txt Success 49,999
/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap104.txt Success 49,999
/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap105.txt Success 49,999
/sitemap-dec2019/sitemap106.txt Success 49,999
1-9 of 9
```

There is nothing different in the Sitemap Index that would make Google select only those 9 specific Sitemap Children.

Under total discovered URLs, it says `449,991` which happens to be 49,999 x 9.

When I remove the Sitemap and re-add the Sitemap Index, the **same** 9 Sitemap Children get listed, and none of the others appear anywhere.

Considering there are over 100 Sitemap Children, this means more than 90% are being completely ignored.

How can I fix this so that all 100% of the Sitemap Children (and their respective URLs) get discovered?

Comment: Have you read [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)?   Sitemaps don't improve your rankings or usually even get pages indexed.   It isn't worth spending a lot of time on them if they are having problems.